# this.setState no actualiza el DOM en mi aplicacion de React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Desarrollo una página de rankigs donde traigo de un backend los datos y después se los paso al componente de `RankingList` para que los ordene y posteriormente los pinte.

Pero validando `this.state.data`, cuando se la paso como props al Componente hijo, me doy cuenta de que no se actualizó cuando apliqué el `setState` en el método  `fetchdata()` en el `componenteDidMount()`.

Debería actualizar, ya que estoy llamado a `setState()` y actualizar.

Este es el código:

```
class Ranking extends Component {
  state = {
    notfound: false,
    data: [],
  };
  componentDidMount() {
   if(!localStorage.getItem('usertoken')){
      this.setState({notfound: true})
    }else{

      this.fecthData();
    }
  }

  fecthData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/getusers", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      this.setState({ data : data });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  

  render() {
    if (this.state.notfound) {
      return <NotFound />;
    }
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="container container-rk   rounded">
          <h1 className="title-ranking">Ranking</h1>
          <ul className="list-group">
            
            <RankList users={this.state.data} />

          </ul>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default Ranking;
```

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el codigo de `<RankList/>`? Puedes bajar las [herramientas de desarrollador de react](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) y revisar si el elemento padre se actualizó correctamente para poder descartar que el que no lo está haciendo bien es el hijo. De ser así el error estaría en ese código.

Comment: Gracias men por responser a mi llamado, ya encontre cual es el error, resulta que me olvide que en React los datos van hacia bajo, y cuando yo manda los datos hacia **RankList** , esos datos se  perdían, porque la función que recibía esos datos y los ordenaba se ejecuta después, porque la tenia en componentDidmount(), asi que lo que hice fue cambiar a RankList con una función, (ya  no necesitaba tener un estado local), en lugar de una clase. Esta funcion tomara los datos y  los procesara  de una vez y asi evitar la perdida de datos.

Comment: Buena solución! Yo me quité las clases de encima con react aprendiendo a usar [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), es mucho más sencillo y fácil.